# In the game engine why do variables link clists from globalDict instead of copying them?

Tags: scripting, game-engine

```
#initial globalDict entries    
bge.logic.globalDict["integer"] = 1
bge.logic.globalDict["clist"] = [0, 1]

#variable assignment
integer = bge.logic.globalDict["integer"]
clist = bge.logic.globalDict["clist"]

#variable modification
integer = integer +1
clist.append(2)
```

Result:
original integer: 1
manually modified integer: 2
integer in globalDict: 1
original clist: [0, 1]
manually modified clist: [0, 1, 2]
clist in globalDict: [0, 1, 2]

The code above shows how changing a different type of variables may or may not change the source of the variable.
Is there a particular reason for that inconsistency?
Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this_is_a_list = [0,1,2,3,4]
this_points_to_the_same_data = this_is_a_list
this_copies_an_item_from_the_list = this_is_a_list[1]
```

A list (or array, dictionary, object...) is a composite type that may contain thousands of items and could consume a GB of ram, assigning a composite type to a new variable only assigns a value that points to the same data as the original variable. You need to manually copy the entire item if that is what you desire.

It may also help to understand that `this_is_a_list` is only a pointer or reference to where the data is stored in ram, the `[]` is used to specify which part of the ram used by the object you wish to read. So using `=` is assigning the same reference to the new variable.

This is mostly a performance decision (it is the way python works not just blender), a single number consumes a similar amount (dependant on the number and 32/64 bit system being used) of ram as a pointer to a large composite data type. These values can easily be passed between functions within the cpu without any performance penalty. Copying an entire compound data type can consume large amounts of ram and take seconds to copy, so is not performed unless you specifically want to copy the entire thing.

To get a full copy you can use copy()

```
this_copies_the_entire_list = this_is_a_list.copy()
```

`copy()` is useful as it can be used for lists and dictionaries. For lists you can also copy them with `blist = alist[:]` or `blist = [x for x in alist]` which also allows you to add an `if` test to copy part of the list.

Comment: Do I need to do more than just use .copy() at the end of a clist in order to make the variable copy instead of link the list? Because right now i've tried exactly what you proposed, modified the this_copies_the_entire_list afterwards and this_is_a_list was changed too.

Comment: No you just need `clist = bge.logic.globalDict["clist"].copy()` to copy the whole list. There is also a deepcopy available which will also copy lists inside lists, if you have them in your real code. `import copy clist = copy.deepcopy(bge.logic.globalDict["clist"])`